# Yank with Separate Line Pasting

Tags: cut-copy-paste

Given

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

I want to `5yy` and then separately paste 5 lines in arbitrary locations in order of `a` `b` `c` `d` `e` instead of a separate `yy` `p` for each line.

Are there any plugins or Vim script that would service this type of workflow?
Or is there a basic set of macros that would help me achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you paste into order, we could imagine something that consumes one line in the unnamed register (or any other) each time it's used.

```
:nnoremap £ :call append('.', matchstr(getreg(v:register),"\\v.{-}\\ze\n"))<cr>:call setreg(v:register, substitute(getreg(v:register) , "\\v.{-}(\n\|$)", '', ''))<cr>
```

(Of course, a function (and using `:put=` instead of `append()`) would be better. This is just a quick and dirty solution. From a function we could have used `matchlist()` instead of `matchstr()` + `substitute()`)